# R: Combine data frames by multiple IDs, align by second ID if they match, otherwise insert NA

Tags: r, join, merge

I have two dataframes of strings that look like this

```
df1
firm_id    user_id_source1
"1234"     "abc"
"1234"     "bcd"
"1234"     "cde"
"1234"     "def"
"1234"     "fgh"
"2345"     "zyx"
"2345"     "yxw"
"2345"     "xwv"
"2345"     "wvu"
"2345"     "vut"
```

And

```
df2
firm_id    user_id_source2
"1234"     "abc"
"1234"     "bcd"
"1234"     "ghi"
"1234"     "hij"
"2345"     "zyx"
"2345"     "yxw"
"2345"     "utr"
```

There are many firms that each have many user ids. I am looking to combine where the user id's match, followed by the rest of the data without losing any data because the source of the user id is important. Like this:

```
result
firm_id    user_id_source1    user_id_source2
"1234"     "abc"               "abc"
"1234"     "bcd"               "bcd"
"1234"     "cde"               NA
"1234"     "def"               NA
"1234"     "fgh"               NA
"1234"     NA                  "ghi"
"1234"     NA                  "hij"
"2345"     "zyx"               "zyx"
"2345"     "yxw"               "yxw"
"2345"     "xwv"               NA
"2345"     "wvu"               NA
"2345"     "vut"               NA
"2345"     NA                  "utr"
```

I have tried every type of join and merge and can't figure this out. Any help is very much appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT: r-schifini below solved this issue. Thank you. 
I added

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% arrange(firm_id, is.na(user_id_source1), is.na(user_id_source2))
```

to arrange in the desired order.

EDIT2: I was already using dplyr so it wasn't a problem for me but I figured someone down the road might want to keep it in base R. Here is how to sort this is base R.

```
df_ordered <- df[order(df$firm_id, is.na(df$user_id_source1), is.na(df$user_id_source2)),]
```

Comment: have you try with `merge(df1,df2,by="firm_id", all= TRUE)`?

Comment: Yes, this just gives the cross-product within each firm_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the data frames by two columns: `firm_id` and `user_id` (1 and 2). Since user_id columns have different names and you want to keep them then do:

```
df1 = data.frame(firm_id = c('1234','1234','5678','5678'),user_id_1 = c('abc','bcd','abc','xyz'))
df2 = data.frame(firm_id = c('1234','3456','5678'),user_id_2 = c('abc','bcd','xyz'))

# Create a copy of the user_id columns with a common name: 'user'
df1$user = df1$user_id_1
df2$user = df2$user_id_2

# do a full merge (they will be merged by 'firm_id' and 'user')
df = merge(df1, df2, all = T)

# remove the 'user' column
df$user = NULL
```

Result:

```
> df1
  firm_id user_id_1 user
1    1234       abc  abc
2    1234       bcd  bcd
3    5678       abc  abc
4    5678       xyz  xyz

> df2
  firm_id user_id_2 user
1    1234       abc  abc
2    3456       bcd  bcd
3    5678       xyz  xyz

> df
  firm_id user_id_1 user_id_2
1    1234       abc       abc
2    1234       bcd      <NA>
3    5678       abc      <NA>
4    5678       xyz       xyz
5    3456      <NA>       bcd
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you. I am embarrassed at how much time I spent on this today. I added ```library(dplyr);
df <- df %>% arrange(firm_id, is.na(user_id_source1), is.na(user_id_source2))``` to arrange in the desired order.